# Navigate to screen without onPressed or something similar

Tags: flutter, widget

I want to navigate from my `Launcher` screen to my `secondScreen`. I am trying to this with:

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SomeScreen()));
```

I want this function to run when a specific variable in the `state` is modified. So I don't want it to run with an `onPressed:` or an `onTap:`

If I just call it in the `build` function of the `Launcher` widget I get the error:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return StoreConnector<AppState, AppState>(
        converter: (store) => store.state,
        builder: (context, state) {
            Navigator.push(
               context,
               MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SomeScreen()));
```

```
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.

This Overlay widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets.  A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built. Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.
The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was: Overlay-[LabeledGlobalKey<OverlayState>#39c7e]
  state: OverlayState#759c1(entries: [OverlayEntry#f9b89(opaque: true; maintainState: false), OverlayEntry#1ff83(opaque: false; maintainState: true), OverlayEntry#5208b(opaque: false; maintainState: false), OverlayEntry#67aa9(opaque: false; maintainState: true)])
The widget which was currently being built when the offending call was made was: StreamBuilder<AppState>
  dirty
  state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<AppState, AsyncSnapshot<AppState>>#472c9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `addPostFrameCallback`

```dart
 WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
Navigator.push(
               context,
               MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SomeScreen()));});
```

not ideal

Comment: Right will work but very bad structure.

Comment: I found this online but it is very dirty… isn‘t there another way? Can I use 'state' in it? And should it be in the build function?

Comment: I thought it didn't work but I forgot to alter my state, so it pushed 3 times and I thought it wouldn't work... thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
    converter: (store) => store.state
```

can't you use

```
    converter: (store) {
        store.state;
        Navigator.push(
           context,
           MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SomeScreen()));
```

Comment: Can I put a delay in there?

Comment: You can try to make it async. Just add async - await keywords.